# iOS double method argument failure

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

I have some framework code that does this:

```
#ifdef USE_DOUBLE
typedef double real;
#else
typedef float real;
#endif
```

But when I attempt to use this type when `USE_DOUBLE` is *defined* (so real == double) like so:

```
- (id) initSomeObject:(real)arg  andSomeOtherStuff:(id)thing
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        field = arg;
    }
}

[someObject initSomeObject:2.0  andSomeOtherStuff:nil];
```

the `arg` value is completely trashed, appearing as 5.3...e-315. **However**, if I switch `USE_DOUBLE` *off*, the value of `2.0` works perfectly. This is on the latest iOS 5+, using Xcode 4.3.3 and LLVM 3.1, on an iPhone 4. Does iOS not handle doubles well? Should my `USE_DOUBLE` flag always be undef'd?

Comment: double type definitely is supported. may be not all of your files see the same type. for example, some file see real as double, but some other file see real as float

Comment: What type has your `field` ? Maybe there is implicit casting from `real` to `field` which in case of `double` is flawed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The define `USE_DOUBLE` and type `real` are defined in a static library, which my application consumes. Turns out that `USE_DOUBLE` needs to be set to the **same value** in the *framework* and in the *client application* for the `typedef` to work correctly. It seems that my application was considered a separate compilation unit, meaning because it did not have `USE_DOUBLE` defined, `real` was a float. This caused the runtime to narrow the precision of my values and cause unexpected/undefined behavior. Adding `#define USE_DOUBLE` into my application project seems to have solved this issue.

Comment: This seems to defeat the purpose of the `#define` in the static library if the value also must be set in my client application. This make me believe I am misusing the `#define`. What is a better way to be able to recompile my static library with float or double precision independent of the client application?